# pattern matching and regular expression in perl?

Tags: perl

i am working on chet-bot program in perl and regular expression but i am not getting the desired results  as you see i have all pronouns and verbs in hash and i am loop through string and if it match hash key then replace hash key value with the current substring value.

**program output** 
**Eliza:** Hi, I'm a psychotherapist. What is your name? 
**adam:** my name is adam
**Eliza:** Hello  adam , How are you? 
**adam:** i am feeling bad 
**Eliza:** Why you am feeling bad ? 
**adam:** because i am sick
**Eliza:** Why because you am sick?

regardless of "because" word in last question but output should be something like this

**Eliza:** Why because you are sick?
any suggestions of how i can solve this issue.

***code:***

```
sub makeQuestion{
    my ($patient) = @_;
    my %reflections = (
        "am"    =>   "are ",
        "was"   =>   "were ",
        "i"     =>   "you ",
        "i'd"   =>   "you would ",
        "i've"  =>   "you have ",
        "i'll"  =>   "you will ",
        "my"    =>   "your ",
        "are"   =>   "am ",
        "you've"=>   "I have ",
        "you'll"=>   "I will ",
        "your"  =>   "my ",
        "yours" =>   "mine ",
        "you"   =>   "me ",
        "me"    =>   "you "
    );

    my @toBes = keys %reflections;
    foreach my $toBe (@toBes) {
        if ($patient =~/$toBe\b/)
        {
            $patient=~ s/$toBe /$reflections{$toBe}/i;

        }

    }
    print "Why $patient? \n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As suggested by @zdin, I replace `'\s'` by `' '` which will match any number of whitespaces and also ignore leading whitespaces.

That's because you are looping over the full key of your %reflections hash and make systematic replacements. Therefore, you find the "am" key at loop 1 and replace it with "are". Then you find the "are" key at loop 8 and replace it with "am".

As you make single word replacements, you should rather ensure you run over a single word only once by using split:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $question = '';

while ($question ne 'stop') {
    $question = <STDIN>;
    chomp $question;
    print makeQuestion($question)."\n";
}

sub makeQuestion{
    my ($patient) = @_;
    my @new_question;
    my %reflections = (
        "am"    =>   "are",
        "was"   =>   "were",
        "i"     =>   "you",
        "i'd"   =>   "you would",
        "i've"  =>   "you have",
        "i'll"  =>   "you will",
        "my"    =>   "your",
        "are"   =>   "am",
        "you've"=>   "I have",
        "you'll"=>   "I will",
        "your"  =>   "my",
        "yours" =>   "mine",
        "you"   =>   "me",
        "me"    =>   "you",
    );
    WORDS: foreach my $word (split ' ', $patient) {
        REPLACE: foreach my $key (keys %reflections) {
            if ($word =~ m{\A$key\Z}i) {
                $word =~ s{$key}{$reflections{$key}}i;
                 last REPLACE;
            }
        }
       push @new_question, $word;
    }
    return join ' ', @new_question;
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, for its flexibility. It is very easy to tweak, when new needs come up. A couple of comments. There isn't much benefit to first testing (with a regex match) in order to process (with a regex substitution) -- if `s/` doesn't match it won't change its target. I think that in this case `\b` sufficies as an anchor, and that loop labels make it perhaps less readable (as a matter of taste, of course).  However, they are certainly useful as demonstrations.

Comment: In fact, since you nicely `split` into words first there is no reason for an anchor, since a word is tested against a word. But I'd suggest to split by any amount of whitespace, to be on the safe side. The default for this is `' '` pattern (or of course the equivalent `/\s*/`). These comments aren't meant to detract from the answer, which I think is good and useful to have :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications zdin. However that's where I meet my own limits in perl: I want to avoid multiple substitutions, that's why I let the test in place: in order to be sure that a single word is substituted only once. If I don't use the test, how I will know that a substitution took place and subsequently stop the loop to switch to the next word?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. It's safe though, since the code runs through a fixed list of `$word`s -- they are not aliased (when a word changes the list and the `$patient` don't). However, you are right that you must stop looping. Which can be done by capturing `{($key)}{...}` and then `last if $1`.  But that may be silly, as capturing is done _only_ to be able to test. There are internal regex variables that can be queried to see whether a match occurred, but then that may be a little tricky. Now, this part is a disadvantage of explicit looping - there are the details :).

Answer (score 3):

Your code makes circular replacements, since it always processes the whole phrase. It replaces a word, only to later replace *that* replacement.  The [answer by David Verdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42019311/4653379) explains it and shows a way to fix this.

Here is another way

```
my $phrase =  join ' ', map { $reflections{$_} // $_ } split ' ', $patient;
```

The list of words produced by [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is fed to [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), which applies the code in the block to each.  Inside the block the currently processed element is in the default [$_ variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables).

If the word is a key in the hash with a `defined` value then that value is returned, otherwise the word itself is returned. This is achieved by `//`, the [*defined-or* operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or). Thus all words that have a hash key get replaced by the corresponding values, while others are passed along unchanged.  Their order is kept as well so we get our list of words processed as needed.

That output list is then joined by space, forming the phrase to be prepended by `'Why '`

Note that the pattern `' '` in `split` matches any amount of any whitespace. It is commonly used to break strings "by space" (into "words") and is `split`'s default.

---

I'd like to add a comment on the regular expression use in the posted code. You don't need to first test for a match in order to do the substitution. You can just do

```
foreach my $item (@list) {
    $item =~ s/$pattern/$repl/;
}
```

and if the `$pattern` doesn't match in `$item` nothing happens, the `$item` is unchanged.

Comment: @DavidVerdin  Well, thank you. I'd like to note though that procedural, item-by-item, solutions (like yours) have clear advantages.  Firstly, they are more flexible -- one can just add code as more processing gets needed. When it's folded in a `map` it may be harder to tweak things.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in the particular phrase/sentence, there are two eligible candidates  in matching your regex. And also, the fact is, elements of hashes are ordered in a random way in memory. In your code, you just got the keys of `%refelections` , you did not provide for sorting that. Therefore, every run, `keys %reflections` will return array of different sorting. For example, in Run 1, it might be `( 'am', 'i', 'my', me' ... )`, then next run `( 'i', "you'll', 'my', 'yours' )`.